# Google Analytics Enhanced-Ecommerce transactions update

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

In many cases consumer change their mind and ask to change their order or the fulfillment has to change the original order. 
The current API only supports [refunds](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-refunds) and not updates.

Use Cases:

1. Consumer wants to update their order after it was checked out (, e.g. increase the amount of milk in the ordered)
2. Fulfillment supply less than was order due to stock limitation.

Is there a way to update a transaction?